# How to access html file inside iframe in production

Tags: iframe, nextjs-rewrites

I am creating a web app where, this app will generate a .html file in `public/` directory. And after that i want to show that `generated html file` on a page using `iframe` .

I am using `NextJS` for this task. I have configured `next.config.js` for `rewrites` but getting `404 error`. I am using [Railway](https://railway.app/) for hosting. Since in [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) we can not access filesystem [here](https://vercel.com/guides/why-does-my-serverless-function-work-locally-but-not-when-deployed?query=file%20system#reading-from-or-writing-to-the-filesystem).

Instead of generating html dynamically, if I upload that .html file, then i can access that file using `iframe` in production.
I think we can not access those files which were not available during build process. (this is my guess , maybe wrong)

How can I solve this problem or should I use another framework ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I was accessing .html files (i.e `<iframe src="path-to-file"></iframe>`) which were not available during `build` process, that's why i was getting `404 error`.

So I did the following thing:
suppose I want to do this `<iframe src="/pdf/page01.xhtml"></iframe>` where file location is in `public/pdf/page01.xhtml`.

so this `src` is sending a `GET` request to `localhost:3000/pdf/page01.xhtml`.
To manipulate this `request` I created a `pages/api/pdf/[...slug].js`. In this file you can use `process.cwd()` to access the file inside your `public` dir. You read file content using `fs.readFile` and send the response `res.status(200).send(data)` like this.

By doing this I was getting the desired result.

Suggestions are always welcome.